# Can I use exception as a recursive function instead of using goto in this C++ program

Tags: visual-c++, c++17

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int exp(int b){
    try{
        throw b;
    }
    catch(int b){
        cout<<"Enter b again : ";
        cin>>b;
    }
    if(b==0)
        exp(b);    //this is the part where I think a logical error is occuring
    return b;
}

int main(){
    system("cls");
    int a, b;
    cout<<"Enter a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter b: ";
    cin>>b;
    if(b==0)
        exp(b);
    cout<<"Division a/b = "<<a/b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to avoid using goto function in this program and instead use exception as a recursive funtion in this program, but it is showing the output like this

```
Enter a: 6
Enter b: 0
Enter b again : 0 
Enter b again : 7 
Enter b again : 5 
Enter b again :
```

Comment: Why would `goto` be needed? Why start a function by throwing an exception? What is it that you would like the program to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can do lots of things in C++. That doesn't mean you *should* do them. Using exceptions for non-exceptional events is one of them. As it says in [the C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Re-errors):

> To keep error handling separated from "ordinary code." C++ implementations tend to be optimized based on the assumption that exceptions are rare.

In short, exception handling is very slow. Exceptions are useful to many C++ programmers because they enable error handling that doesn't slow down normal execution; only costing time when the error actually occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently didn't understand how `try - catch` statement even works. When program's execution flow reaches a `throw` statement, an appropriate catch() block of most recently entered try-catch statement will be considered. In your case you have a conditionless `throw`, thus your function is an equivalent of this code, no try-catch is required:

```
int exp(int b)
{
    cout<<"Enter b again : ";
    cin>>b;

    if(b==0)
        exp(b);    //this is the part where I think a logical error is occuring
    return b;
}
```

So you ask b to be entered again, if b is zero you ask it to be entered again ... and exit the cycle when b isn't zero, but it would e always prompting to enter a value. All this could be done by single `do .. while` without recursion, and obviously you have to check value of b  before  the input prompt, you you would miss result of first input.

Second , you don't actually user return value, neither you pass it by reference, so b in main() function would stay zero. You may as well use something like

```
void exp(int& b)
{
    while(b==0) {
        std::cout << "Enter b again : ";
        std::cin >> b;
    }
}
```

Note, that this still got a flaw, not accounting for case when user had entered incorrect, not-a-number input.

`try-catch` is slow because it can unwind stack of calls and isn't appropriate as a flow control statement. `throw` can be encountered in any function called anywhere, on any nested level between `try` and `catch`, but returning from catch would gracefully exit scopes of all functions in stack before passing execution to `catch`.

Comment: I know this way and also know that do-while way is the efficient way, but I wanted to know what I could do this problem using try-catch exception handling.